# pass SSH as argument into ansible-playbook

Tags: docker, ssh, ansible, docker-image

I have Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

ARG ssh_prv_key
ARG ssh_pub_key

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install ... USUAL INSTALL STUFF ...

WORKDIR /app/

CMD git clone MY_REPO
```

I build image like this:

```
$ docker build -t example --build-arg ssh_prv_key="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)" --build-arg ssh_pub_key="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)" .
```

When I create container from this image it automaticaly pulls git-repo and save it on host using `-v` argument and self-destroyes using `--rm`.

The problem begins when I try to do same things using ansible docker_image module.

playbook looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  environment:
    PYTHONPATH: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

  tasks:
  - name: create image from Dockerfile
    docker_image:
      path: /home/demaunt/Jun/dock_click
      dockerfile: biba.dockerfile
      name: myimage
      buildargs: 
        ssh_pub_key: '{{ pub }}'
        ssh_prv_key: '{{ pvt }}'
```

I start it like this:

```
ansible-playbook bibansible.yml --extra-vars "pub=$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) pvt=$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)"
```

The image is built succesfully, but when running container I get Permission error (publickey).
I also tried to pass arguments into .yml file like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  environment:
    PYTHONPATH: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

  tasks:
  - name: create image from Dockerfile
    docker_image:
      path: /home/demaunt/Jun/dock_click
      dockerfile: biba.dockerfile
      name: myimage
      buildargs: 
        ssh_pub_key:
          command: cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
        ssh_prv_key: 
          command: cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

P.S. I understand that passing ssh keys into image is not the best option,  but it is acceptable as temporary solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `command` at this level in ansible.
But to get the content of a local file, take a look at [`lookup`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_lookups.html#intro-to-lookups-getting-file-contents)

```
[...]
buildargs: 
    ssh_pub_key: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
    ssh_prv_key: "{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/id_rsa') }}"
```